# Showing that linear operator is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a real Banach space and $T: X \rightarrow X^*$ a linear operator such that $[T(x)](x) \geq 0$ for all $ x \in X$. Prove that $T$ is bounded.

So, I need to prove that there exists an $M \geq 0$ such that $\|T(x)\| \leq M \|x\|$, for all $x \in X$.

I can't really see where to start with this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yup, it does. Thanks!